# How can i push this div up so it sits under the other one?

Tags: css, html

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/

**I have this form:**

[image]

If you look in the image, The 3rd box goes below because the 2nd box is pushing it down, Is there a way that i can have the 3rd box sit underneath the 1st box so there isnt so much white space?

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!--Open Main Wrapper  -->

<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
        <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
</div>

<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>

            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> <!--Close Main Wrapper  -->
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
.selection_list {
    width:460px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.selectionleft{
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:5px; 
}
.selectionright{
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    margin:5px; 
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: You have margin: 10px; on the list. Which means it will require a margin of 10px in all directions... change this...

Comment: The float can't work with different heights alone. Check this plug-in if you can use it http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Are the boxes always the same size?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: No they're not always the same size, always different, sometimes the same. It just looks silly at the moment because if the top left has 1 entry, the top right has 15 then there is so much white space. Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/

Comment: i already did in the last comment, Here:  jsfiddle.net/2vLYn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two wrappers:  and  then float those two together. Inside the first wrapper you put two of the small lists and in the other wrapper you put the big one and a small one. This should solve the problem.

I added a code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/1/

Notice this change

`<div id="wrapone"> <!-- FIRST WRAP -->`

and this change

`#wrapone {
    width: 500px;
    float:left;
}`

Comment: That only removes the 10px, It will place it right next to the 2nd box not remove all that white space.

Comment: Oh, I see! You want to columns? Okai, you should use 2 wraps on this one. The reason is because, float: left; just take the next element in order and puts it there. The third element is then put as far down as the biggest element on the last line. Which creates this huge white space...

Comment: What do you mean 2 wraps? I'm still need with this.

Comment: use two of these `<div id="wrapperone">` and `<div id="wrappertwo">` then float those two together. Inside the first wrapper you put two of the small lists and in the other wrapper you put the big one and a small one. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Would you mind showing me on jsfiddle, i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/CajBB/ but didnt work

Comment: Updated my answer now, with the jsfiddle :) Even better looking would if you added the other small list in the first wrapper too :) Here is the code for that `http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/3/`

Comment: the only issue is im having it list from a php while loop which gets the data from a database, how can i tell it to post one in the left and the one in the right? :(

Comment: That is something you can decide, but since you have 2 wrappers you have to echos from the database. You just have to make a statement that decideds what data gets where... use ID number to decide this... like ID 1,2 and 3 goes on left side and 4,5 and 6 on right side :) Getting data to the correct place shouldn't be hard in PHP, as you have to have a PHP function inside a wrapper anyways :) You just have two instead! :)

Comment: ok fair enough, i will have to try work it out. thanks for your help.

Comment: Anytime! :) If you need help with the PHP just flick me a chat and I can help out :) Would you mind accepting answer if it helped? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40389/discussion-between-exoon-and-friedbitz)

Answer (score 0):

make separate wrapper divs for .selectionleft and .selectionright and then float that wrapper divs this will fix your problum.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CajBB/  the .selectionleft and .selectionright are inside a .selection-wrapper which is float:left but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
.selection_list {
    width:460px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.selectionleft{
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:5px; 
}
.selectionright{
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    margin:5px; 
    font-size:14px;
}
#leftColumn{
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
}
#rightColumn{
    float:right;
    width: 480px;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"> <!--Open Main Wrapper  -->

<div id="leftColumn">
    <div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title 1</strong></div>
        <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
        <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title 3</strong></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rightColumn">

<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title 2</strong></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>



<div class="selection_list">
    <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title 4</strong></div>

            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
</div>

</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> <!--Close Main Wrapper  -->
</body>
</html>
```

But yes I assumed that the boxes are of same sizes, but you can tweak that on your own

Comment: The only trouble is im going to be having a list of lists in a php while loop, how can i tell which one to go into the left column and which to go into the right column?

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 seperate wrappers and place the divs within the relevant wrapper, e.g.:

**CSS**:

```
#left-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}
#right-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:400px;      
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-wrapper">         
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
                <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
                <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-wrapper"> 
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
                <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong></div>
        </div>
     </div>            
</div>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/6/

Answer (score 0):

## Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLYn/8/)** with verified result.

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--Open Main Wrapper -->
    <div style="float:left">
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong>

            </div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong>

            </div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"> <strong>Title</strong>

            </div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionleft">Checkbox</div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selection_list">
            <div style="padding:3px; margin:3px; font-size:16px;"><strong>Title</strong>

            </div>
            <div class="selectionright"><strong>This is where some text will go</strong>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<!--Close Main Wrapper -->
```

### CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
.selection_list {
    width:460px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.selectionleft {
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:5px;
}
.selectionright {
    left:13px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:16px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```